# pyspark: concatenate column pairs from two lists into new columns

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, concatenation

Given two lists of strings of column names from a pyspark DataFrame, I'd like to create new columns based on the pairwise concatenation of the strings. I have a working solution, but I am curious if there are any better solutions (in terms of performance, being more idiomatic/pythonic, or other concerns).

```
schema = 'row int, w string, x string, y string, z string'
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pandas as pd
test = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame({'row': [1, 2, 3],
                       'w': ['w', 'w', 'w'],
                       'x': ['x', 'x', 'x'],
                       'y': ['y', 'y', 'y'],
                       'z': ['z', 'z', 'z']}),
                      schema=schema)
test.show()

+---+---+---+---+---+
|row|  w|  x|  y|  z|
+---+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  w|  x|  y|  z|
|  2|  w|  x|  y|  z|
|  3|  w|  x|  y|  z|
+---+---+---+---+---+

cols1 = ['w', 'y']
cols2 = ['x', 'z']
for c1, c2 in zip(cols1, cols2):
    test = test.withColumn(c1 + c2, F.concat_ws('_', c1, c2))

test.show()
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|row|  w|  x|  y|  z| wx| yz|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  w|  x|  y|  z|w_x|y_z|
|  2|  w|  x|  y|  z|w_x|y_z|
|  3|  w|  x|  y|  z|w_x|y_z|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

I am working on Databricks DBR 14.3 ML LTS, using Spark 3.5.0, Scala 2.12.15, and Python 3.10.12.